# itext multiline text on diagonal

Tags: c#-4.0, itext

How i can add a multi-line text with **itext** on diagonal. meaning that if the text is to large for the first diagonal(the largest diagonal) it should move on the next or above diagonal and so one, to see all the text.

I already calculated the text angle for the diagonal and uses `pdfcontentbyte` to stamp but if my text is longer than the diagonal the rest of the words that don't fit on the diagonal it is not showed. I think i have to make something mathematical or i saw something with `setsimplecolumn` and chunks but this will show my text aligned horizontal. 
If anyone has some ideas? Thanks, and of course need some code examples.

[image: something like this i want(the picture simulates a pdf), where the black lines will be the text, it can be more than three lines if the text is bigger,it is dynamic]

Answer (score 0):

Don't shoot me if I'm wrong, but based on your description I think you're talking about 'irregular columns'. See http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=67

This type of column isn't a rectangle. Basically, you define coordinates for the left border (can be a diagonal line) and coordinates for the right border. Then you pour text between these two lines.

If that's not what you meant, maybe you want to write text diagonally. In that case, you can still use ColumnText, but you need to change the coordinate system, so that the text isn't written in horizontal lines from left to right, but in diagonal lines from top to bottom (or bottom to top). Changing the coordinate system is done with the `concatCTM` method.

Comment: the second one with the text diagonal, can you give me an example of how to use concatCT and ColumnText, i don't seem to make it work. thanks.., essentially i want to write text diagonally and if text is to long to write on the biggest diagonal, get to the up diagonal, if the text is still big, get to the down diagonal of the first diagonal. something recursively

Comment: Based on your drawing, I see that the concatCTM method isn't going to be sufficient. Why not? Because I suggested that you should create your column first, and then rotate it. However: there's no way to know in advance how many diagonal lines you'll need. You can't determine the 'shape' of the irregular column in advance.

Comment: So you'll have to do plenty of math. Take the String, measure its width, then do a couple of iterations to find out how to cut the String into different pieces. Finally draw line by line with ColumnText.showTextAligned() using an x, y coordinate in the middle, centered alignment, and the desired angle. By the way: the extra drawing was very helpful to understand the problem! Thanks!

Comment: ok, thank you , i thought there is a method to avoid the math, but it seems it isn't , i will try to do the math and bring here the result..., thank you for your time.